# Proguard error while building an apk using export signed application android

Tags: android

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Warning: com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView: can't find referenced method 'int getLayoutDirection()' in class com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
 Warning: com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView: can't find referenced method 'void setLayoutDirection(int)' in class android.view.View
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
          You may need to recompile them and try again.
          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Progaurd issue in android, not able to build production version of the apk, but able to run on the device, but when export as signed application,giving me issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to update the proguard config with this line:

```
-keep class se.emilsjolander.** { *; } -dontwarn se.emilsjolander.**
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Iam able to build the apk, but a new problem araised. onBackPressed() used in the code is not working at all. android back button is also not working, the same code is working when we run on the device instead of exporting the android application.         <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: Ok, so accept the answer for this question, and then create a new question and include the code that you are running when the user clicks the back button.  Thanks

Comment: @adavis  i m not getting proguard config file

Comment: I had to use se.emilsjolander instead of com.emilsjolander